# electron: how to hide / show <br /> and <hr /> by button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

Using electron to develop a windows app to parse my json files. Click buttons to open, edit and save correspond json files. The related html codes are

```html
  <div class="rightfixed">
      <div id="jsonName">Empty.</div>
      <div id="TimeJson">
        <div id="Time_StartUTCTimeT"><b>Start UTC Time</b><br />UTC Time when simulation start. [year-month-day
          hour:minute:second.microsecond]</div>
        <input id="Time_StartUTCTime"><br /></input>
        <div id="Time_CelebodyTimeStepT"><b>Celebody Time Step (ms)</b><br />Calculation period for celebody simulation.</div>
        <input id="Time_CelebodyTimeStep"><br /></input>
        <div id="Time_DynamicsTimeStepT"><b>Dynamics Time Step (ms)</b><br />Calculation period for dynamic simulation.</div>
        <input id="Time_DynamicsTimeStep"><br /></input>
        <div id="Time_KinematicsTimeStepT"><b>Kinematics Time Step (ms)</b><br />Calculation period for kinematics simulation.</div>
        <input id="Time_KinematicsTimeStep"><br /></input>
        <div id="Time_OutputTimeStepT"><b>Output Time Step (ms)</b><br />Output archive period for simulation results.</div>
        <input id="Time_OutputTimeStep"><br /></input>
        <div id="Time_TotalSimulationTimeT"><b>Total Simulation Time (s)</b><br />Overall simulation duration.</div>
        <input id="Time_TotalSimulationTime"><br /></input>
      </div>

      <div id="EnvironmentJson">
        <div id="Env_EnvironmentModel" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">EnvironmentModel<br /></div>
        <hr />
        <div id="Env_iCSnT"><b>Gravity Mode Order</b><br />Harmonic order of gravity model (iCSn).</div>
        <input id="Env_iCSn"><br /></input>
        <div id="Env_iCSmT"><b>Gravity Mode Series</b><br />Harmonic series of gravity model (iCSm).</div>
        <input id="Env_iCSm"><br /></input>

        <div id="Env_iGHnT"><b>Magnetic Mode Order</b><br />Harmonic order of magnetic model (iGSn).</div>
        <input id="Env_iGHn"><br /></input>
        <div id="Env_iGHmT"><b>Magnetic Mode Series</b><br />Harmonic series of magnetic model (iGSm).</div>
        <input id="Env_iGHm"><br /></input>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and the js codes are

```js
function TimeJsonInfo_Show() {
    Time_StartUTCTime.style.display = "block";
    Time_CelebodyTimeStep.style.display = "block";
    Time_DynamicsTimeStep.style.display = "block";
    Time_KinematicsTimeStep.style.display = "block";
    Time_OutputTimeStep.style.display = "block";
    Time_TotalSimulationTime.style.display = "block";

    Time_StartUTCTimeT.style.display = "block";
    Time_CelebodyTimeStepT.style.display = "block";
    Time_DynamicsTimeStepT.style.display = "block";
    Time_KinematicsTimeStepT.style.display = "block";
    Time_OutputTimeStepT.style.display = "block";
    Time_TotalSimulationTimeT.style.display = "block";
}
function TimeJsonInfo_Hide() {
    Time_StartUTCTime.style.display = "none";
    Time_CelebodyTimeStep.style.display = "none";
    Time_DynamicsTimeStep.style.display = "none";
    Time_KinematicsTimeStep.style.display = "none";
    Time_OutputTimeStep.style.display = "none";
    Time_TotalSimulationTime.style.display = "none";

    Time_StartUTCTimeT.style.display = "none";
    Time_CelebodyTimeStepT.style.display = "none";
    Time_DynamicsTimeStepT.style.display = "none";
    Time_KinematicsTimeStepT.style.display = "none";
    Time_OutputTimeStepT.style.display = "none";
    Time_TotalSimulationTimeT.style.display = "none";
}
function EnvironmentJsonInfo_Show() {
    Env_EnvironmentModel.style.display = "block";
    Env_iCSn.style.display = "block";
    Env_iCSm.style.display = "block";
    Env_iGHn.style.display = "block";
    Env_iGHm.style.display = "block";

    Env_iCSnT.style.display = "block";
    Env_iCSmT.style.display = "block";
    Env_iGHnT.style.display = "block";
    Env_iGHmT.style.display = "block";
}
function EnvironmentJsonInfo_Hide() {
    Env_EnvironmentModel.style.display = "none";
    Env_iCSn.style.display = "none";
    Env_iCSm.style.display = "none";
    Env_iGHn.style.display = "none";
    Env_iGHm.style.display = "none";

    Env_iCSnT.style.display = "none";
    Env_iCSmT.style.display = "none";
    Env_iGHnT.style.display = "none";
    Env_iGHmT.style.display = "none";
}
btnTimeJson.onclick = function () {
    var Path = jsonPath.innerHTML + "\\Time.json"
    fs.exists(Path, (flag) => {
        if(!flag)
            jsonName.innerHTML = "Time.json does not exist."
        else
            jsonName.style.display = "none"
            fs.readFile(Path,(_err,str) => {
                jsonName.innerHTML = basename(Path)
                jsonContent = JSON.parse(str)
                Time_StartUTCTime.value = jsonContent.StartUTCTime
                Time_CelebodyTimeStep.value = jsonContent['CelebodyTimeStep(ms)']
                Time_DynamicsTimeStep.value = jsonContent['DynamicsTimeStep(ms)']
                Time_KinematicsTimeStep.value = jsonContent['KinematicsTimeStep(ms)']
                Time_OutputTimeStep.value = jsonContent['OutputTimeStep(ms)']
                Time_TotalSimulationTime.value = jsonContent['TotalSimulationTime(s)']

                EnvironmentJsonInfo_Hide()
                TimeJsonInfo_Show()
           })
    })
}
```

When the window is initialized, it is like below with all `<div>` hided except `jsonName`.

[window initialized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELca5.png)

However the `<br />` and `<hr />` still exist.

When clicking for example the `Time` button, the window would like to show contents of my `Time.json` within `<div id="TimeJson">`. And the window appears to be ok.

[window clicking Time button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRbni.png)

But when I click `Environment` button, the `<br />` within `<div id="TimeJson">` makes multiple blank lines before the content within `<div id="EnvironmentJson">`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8ygX.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is there any better solutions to create an app to edit multiple json files within one window? I know that the code is poor because I only learned html/electron for a couple of days :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `br` and `hr` are just like other elements which can be hidden by `display: none`

```css
br,
hr {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
a
<br /> b
<hr /> c
```

2. you can put them inside the `div`s you show / hide so they will be shown only if their parents is visible.
3. I wouldn't use `<hr />` and `<br />` but `border` and `margin` to split the design (ass css) and the content (as html)

---

Another side note: I'd also get rid from all the style modifications (e.g. `style.display = 'none'`) and use css based display (for example `data-` attributes).

For example:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    parent.setAttribute('data-item', index + 1);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent div {
  display: none;
}

.parent[data-item="1"] .child1,
.parent[data-item="2"] .child2,
.parent[data-item="3"] .child3,
.parent[data-item="4"] .child4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child 1</div>
  <div class="child2">child 2</div>
  <div class="child3">child 3</div>
  <div class="child4">child 4</div>
</div>

<button>Show element 1</button>
<button>Show element 2</button>
<button>Show element 3</button>
<button>Show element 4</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I managed to use `display: none` and all the hr br are  gone. But I failed to hide / show them within their parent `div`s, since they are exactly within their parents domain now. for example`<input id="Time_StartUTCTime"><br /></input>`
there is a `<br \>` and I when I hide the `Time_StartUTCTime` input, the `<br />` keeps shown as a blank line. i.e. not controlled by its parents. I don't know if I misunderstand your advice?

Comment: `input` doesn't accept elements so you can't hide input along with `br` or any other elements. You can wrap the input **and** the br / hr with a `div` and show / hide it.

Comment: Thanks! It works. And I really appreciate your side note. To me it really likes a beautiful trick to learn. It reminds me of the time when I was learning C and the teacher was showing me some advanced coding skill.

Comment: With pleasure :) Actually, those tips are kind of standard in web development these days. If the answers your question, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so it might help to other people.